# Full screen windowing system in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am working on an application that will need to be able to run both on a single monitor and multiple monitors.  I currently only know of two approaches to accomplishing what I need and neither is ideal.

If I create one JFrame across all monitors I can use JInternalFrames for my movable windows.  The downside is this approach won't work when I'm on different size/resolution monitors as the toolbar or anything else I add to the JFrame won't line up and I'm potentially left with some of the OS showing through.

Another approach is creating a new JFrame for each graphics device and using JDialogs as my windows.  The downside here is I have less control over the JDialogs and cannot restrict movement.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to constrain the JDialog's position so it can't overlap my toolbar.

Are there better approaches?

Comment: Why cant you use JFrames for each graphics device with JInternalFrames ?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to move windows across screens without doing some hacking to switch the JDesktopPane that owns each JInternalFrame.  Unless I'm mistaken and it's easily done.

Comment: Look into [Drag'n'Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html).

Comment: That might work, with the only drawback I can think of right now being no ability to have a window split across two screens at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with your latter approach and just add a ComponentListener to each of your JDialogs:

```
final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        if (dialog.getBounds().intersects(toolbar.getBounds()))
            moveToAvoidConflict(dialog);
    }
}
```

And your `moveToAvoidConflict()` method would move the dialog up, down, left, or right so it no longer intersected your toolbar.

Comment: That doesn't work when the tool bar is floating.  I'd have to also ignore that when the tool bar was vertical to allow the JDialog to move across screens.  I think that would be defeating the purpose of trying to keep windows behind the tool bar.